# Minimizer of $L^1$ norm to indicator of nonnegative reals over convex integrable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 0$ and otherwise $f(x) =0$.

Is there a good characterization of the minimizer of 
$$
\lVert f - g\rVert_{L^1}
$$
over $g\colon\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ where $g$ is convex, non-decreasing, and satisfies $f \leq g$?

Comment: I don't believe a finite solution exists.

Comment: The "best" choice in the $L^\infty$ sense is $g(x)\equiv 1$. But I don't think there is any function a finite distance from $f$ in the $L^p$ sense for $p<\infty$.

Comment: "The minimizer"? Can you prove that the minimum is attained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no convex function $g$ for which  $\|f-g\|_1$ is finite, even if we forget the restriction $f\le g$.

Indeed, the integrability of $f-g$ implies that $\liminf |f-g|=0$ at both infinities, specifically
$$
\liminf_{x\to -\infty} |g(x)| = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad \liminf_{x\to -\infty} |g(x)-1| = 0
$$
By virtue of convexity these $\liminf$s are actual limits: 
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} g(x) = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to -\infty} g(x) = 1 $$
This forces $g$ to be a *bounded nonconstant convex* function on $\mathbb{R}$, and there are no such things.